# Implementing an abstract class hierarchy -

Tags: c#, class, abstract-class

I make an abstract class hierarchy, for example:

```
abstract public class BaseDirectory {
}

abstract public class BaseUser() {
    protected readonly BaseDirectory _DIR
    BaseUser(BaseDirectory dir) {
        _DIR = dir;
    }
}
```

And then I implement that abstract hierarchy:

```
class MyDirectory : BaseDirectory {
    internal void SomeMethod() {
    }
}

class MyUser : BaseUser {
    MyUser(MyDirectory dir) : base(dir)
    {
    }
    internal void SomeMethod() {
        _DIR.SomeMethod(); // <- how to do this?
    }
}
```

Now, from the `MyUser` class, I want to be able to access the `MyDirectory` instance that I can certainly expect in `dir`. **How does a C# programmer achieve this in style?** Overwrite `_DIR` in `MyUser` with a private property that contains the uncasted MyDirectory, using a cast everywhere, anything else entirely?

Comment: Can you add `SomeMethod` to `BaseDirectory` as an `abstract` method?

Comment: @juharr Let's assume `SomeMethod` is specific to `MyDirectory`/`MyUser` and would have to throw `NotImplementedException` in other implementations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably depends on the use case. But what I would do is use generics in the `BaseUser` abstract class to specify the directory type used:

Image something like this:

```
public abstract class BaseDirectory
{

}

public abstract class BaseUser<TDirectory> where TDirectory : BaseDirectory
{
    protected readonly TDirectory _dir;
    protected BaseUser(TDirectory dir)
    {
        _dir = dir;
    }
}

public class MyDirectory : BaseDirectory
{
    public void SpecificMethod() { }
}

public class MyUser : BaseUser<MyDirectory>
{
    public MyUser(MyDirectory dir) : base(dir)
    {

    }

    internal void SomeMethod()
    {
        // call specific method on type MyDirectory
        _dir.SpecificMethod();
    }
}
```

That way you can acces the _dir-Variable which is of type `MyDirectory` and not `BaseDirectory`. If you need to have multiple instances of `MyUser` with different Directories, you could also make the `MyUser` class generic.

I may be totally wrong, and this is total garbage, but thats at least how I would do it : )

Answer (score 1):

You can savely typecast the `_DIR` field in the `MyUser` class. Through the constructor it is ensured, to have a instane of `MyDirectory` there:

```
(_DIR as MyDirectory).SomeMethod()
```

Comment: This is what I have done for now, but does it fulfil the "in style" requirement?

Comment: What do you mean be "in style"?